# How to extract xml attribute using beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the 'totalvotes' value from this xml:

```
<poll title="User Suggested Number of Players" totalvotes="0" name="suggested_numplayers">
<results numplayers="3+"> </results>
</poll>
```

I've messed around with so many different combinations of the following code, but none of them work.

```
soup.find_all('poll',{'title':'User Suggested Number of Players'})[0].find_all('totalvotes')
```

I'm simply trying to retrieve the value of 0, in this case. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to obtain element, one is using CSS selectors:

```
data = '''<poll title="User Suggested Number of Players" totalvotes="0" name="suggested_numplayers">
<results numplayers="3+"> </results>
</poll>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

# method 1 (select <poll> with attribute "votes")
print(soup.select_one('poll[totalvotes]')['totalvotes'])

# method 2 (more specific, select <poll> that has in attribute title "User Suggested Number of Players")
print(soup.select_one('poll[title="User Suggested Number of Players"][totalvotes]')['totalvotes'])

# method 3 (select <poll> that has <results> inside )
print(soup.select_one('poll:has(results)[totalvotes]')['totalvotes'])
```

Prints:

```
0
0
0
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

To extract from first element

```
soup.find('poll').get('totalvotes')
```

To extract from all the elements

```
for poll in soup.find_all('poll'):
    print (poll.get('totalvotes'))
```